# Building A Function Using Constants From a List

Tags: functions, function-construction, evaluation

I want to build a function of the form

$f(t)= C + \sum_i A_i*Sin(f_i*t+\phi_i)$

Where $(A_i,f_i,\phi_i)$ are amplitudes, frequencies and phases that I have stored in a text file. Here is my attempt:

```
BuildOscFunction[indata_,freqvals_]:=Module[{i,j,sin,func,t},
    func=Mean[indata[[All,2]]];
    For[i=1,i<=Length[freqvals],i++,
        func+=freqvals[[i,2]]*Sin[freqvals[[i,1]]*t+freqvals[[i,3]]];   
    ];
    f[t_]:=func//Evaluate;
    Return[f[t]];   
];
```

Here are example snippets of my data set and list of input parameters:

```
indata[[;;4]]={{0., 1.00105}, {20.0003, 1.00115}, {40.0007, 0.999966}, {60.001, 
1.00177}};

freqvals[[;;4]]={{233.362, 0.000802, 3.93604}, {22.0164, 0.000641, 0.277801}, 
{113.97, 0.00063, 5.8311}, {243.764, 0.000631, 5.94761}}
```

The Evaluate command only works if t is not a local variable inside Module. What I want is to get a fully written-out function that I can use at will. Something like,

```
 func[t_]:=BuildOscFunction[indata,freqvals];
 func[t] = 1.2 + 0.00802Sin[233.362t+3.93] + 0.000641Sin[22.0164t+0.277801]+...etc
 func[2]=1.24
```

EDIT:

Thank you for the several very helpful responses! I ended up finding success using the selected answer using code like this:

```
BuildOscFunction[f_,A_,phi_]:=Function[t,Total[A*Sin[f*t+phi]]];

ExampleModule[indata_,freqvals_]:=Module[{funcbuild,func},
    funcbuild=BuildOscFunction[freqvals[[All,1]],freqvals[[All,2]],freqvals[[All,3]]];
    func[t_]:=funcbuild[t];
];
```

func[t] successfully behaves like a standard function where it can be evaluated, manipulated, plotted, etc. inside of the Module environment.

Comment: `Return` does not mean the same thing in *Mathematica* as it does in other languages.  Generally, you won't need to use it.  To return something from a `Module`, just have it be the last entry in the `Module`, and don't use a semicolon. That is, `Module[{i,j,sin,func,t}, ...; f[t_] := func // Evaluate]`

Comment: How about: `BuildOscFunction[in_List, fv_List] := 
 Mean[in[[All, 2]]] + #[[2]] Sin[#[[1]] t + #[[3]]] & /@ fv // Total` and `BuildOscFunction[indata, freqvals] /. t -> 2` for a single point evaluation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

To be effective with Wolfram Language, you have to change your thinking from "procedural" to "functional". E.g., try to avoid using explicit `Do` loops etc.

In your particular example, it certainly helps that many functions (including `Plus`, `Times` and `Sin`) are `Listable`, e.g., they automatically map over their arguments:

```
Clear[a, b, c]
Sin[{a, b, c}] (* Sin[a], Sin[b], Sin[c]} *)
```

Knowing this, here is one possible solution to your problem:

```
BuildOscFunction[A_, f_, phi_] := Function[t, Total[A Sin[f t + phi]]]


Clear[A, f, phi]
A = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4};
f = {5.7, 3.8, 9.1, 6.5};
phi = {-1, 0.27, 1.35, -2};


g = BuildOscFunction[A, f, phi]
Plot[g[t], {t, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Following suggestions in other answers is a good idea, i.e., avoid the use of loops in *Mathematica*. There are are almost always better ways to do things. That said, to minimally change your code so that it works, I would do the following:

```
buildOscFunction[indata_, freqvals_] := Module[{i, j, sin, func},
  func = Mean[indata[[All, 2]]];
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[freqvals], i++,
    func += freqvals[[i, 2]]*Sin[freqvals[[i, 1]]*t + freqvals[[i, 3]]]];
  f[t_] := func
 ]
```

Then, setting (note that you don't need to declare these as variables before defining these lists!)

```
 indata = {{0., 1.00105}, {20.0003, 1.00115}, {40.0007, 0.999966}, {60.001, 1.00177}};
 freqvals = {{233.362, 0.000802, 3.93604}, {22.0164, 0.000641, 0.277801}, {113.97, 0.00063, 5.8311}, {243.764, 0.000631, 5.94761}};
```

and evaluating

```
 buildOscFunction[indata, freqvals]
```

creates a function of `f[t]` that you can then plot

```
 Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Note a couple of things:

- I have removed the use of `Return`. It's not the same in *Mathematica* as in other languages. Instead, I just leave the expression I want `Module` to return as the last element in the `CompoundExpression` inside the `Module` (and without a semicolon).
- I have removed `t` from the set of scoped variables inside the `Module`. This is because `Module` creates new variable names behind the scenes of the form `t$406471` which will cause problems if you want to evaluate this function later. Leave `t` as an undefined global variables.
- I have used a lower-case first letter for the function name. It's a good habit to be in using when *Mathematica* because all built-in names have capitalized first letters; this way, you won't conflict with built-in functions.

Aesthetically, I might want to define a function name outside the `Module`, in which case I would instead define

```
buildOscFunction[indata_, freqvals_] := Module[{i, j, sin, func},
  func = Mean[indata[[All, 2]]];
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[freqvals], i++,
    func += freqvals[[i, 2]]*Sin[freqvals[[i, 1]]*t + freqvals[[i, 3]]]];
  func
 ]
```

and call the function as

```
func[t_] = buildOscFunction[indata, freqvals];
```

Then, plot `func[t]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
f[t_] := Mean[indata[[All, 2]]] + 
  Plus @@ MapThread[#[[2]] Sin[#[[1]] t + #[[3]]] &, {freqvals}]

Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]